# Why is this jquery validation not submitting?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation

After struggling for doing everything that I want, my jquery validation has stopped submitting the completed form.

The page is here:
https://web.archive.org/web/20160612145452/http://www.fourwoodscountryhearts.co.uk/payments

Comment: Can you post your code? That would be helpful.

Comment: Add a code sample to your post.  Easier to troubleshoot that way.

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: What would be the easiest would be to reproduce your code on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) and then post the fiddle URL

Answer (score 2):

I beleive if you change the line:

```
 debug: true,
```

within the file `paymentsformbits.js` to:

```
 debug: false,
```

it should allow you to submit the form once you complete the validation process.

It thinks you are testing the script, so doesn't do the final submit. Once you finish testing *(debugging)* and go live, you should set it to false!

---

**Demo**

You'll have to complete basic validation, but one will try to submit and show an error, the other won't do anything just like you are experiencing.

Here is the script with `debug: true` [jsFiddle - Demo 1](http://jsfiddle.net/8Jnku/) 
Here it the script with `debug: false` [jsFiddle - Demo 2](http://jsfiddle.net/8Jnku/1/)

---

**Reason**

This is the line of code from the validation script `jquery.validate.js` which stops the form if `debug: true`:

```
// validate the form on submit
this.submit( function( event ) {
    if ( validator.settings.debug )
        // prevent form submit to be able to see console output
        event.preventDefault();
```

Comment: That works a treat, thank you! So what does this section of code (in the head) do?<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
 debug: true,
 success: "valid"
});
</script>

Comment: Sorry I've logged off my computer, I'm on my phone so can't view the source now, but from what you have posted, it is simply the default for all validators on that page. You are overriding the default debug setting from the head with the debug: true declaration. At a guess, with that default, if you removed debug: false, you would find the form stop submitting again as it would fall back on what is set as the default. That's just speculation till I can double check. Glad to have helped and good luck with the site!

Comment: Just had a quick look now I'm back on a laptop, and it is indeed just default settings, which if un-set in the setup of the validator (`$("#paymentsform").validate({`) will take the role. If you look at the two demo's posted, they don't have the default settings set, so technically you don't need that bit in your head. And tbh I would also suggest setting the default debug setting to false if you want to leave the settings in the head section of your page. If you did that, you could, but its not vital, remove the whole line `debug: false,` from the validator.

Comment: Sorry I haven't replied sooner, it's been a busy couple of weeks here. Just wanted to say thanks for your time in looking into this for me, It's been a real help.